# Bug?? If you assign a value to a nullable integer via a ternary operator, it can't become null

Tags: vb.net, nullable, ternary-operator

```
dim val1 As Integer? = If(5 > 2, Nothing, 43)
' val1 = 0

dim val1 As Integer? = If(5 > 2, Nothing, Nothing)
' val1 = Nothing
```

What gives?  Is this a bug, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `Nothing` in VB.NET works differently than, for example, `null` in C#. When `Nothing` is used in the context of a value type (such as `Integer`) it represents the default value of that type. In this case, that's 0.

In your first example, both branches of the ternary operator are valid `Integer` values. The true branch represents 0 and the false branch represents 43.

In the second example, neither branch of the ternary operator is a valid `Integer` value, thus forcing the VB.NET compiler to assume that the overall operator returns `Object`, not `Integer`.

To make the first example work the way you intend, you need to make it clear to the compiler that the ternary operator should resolve to an `Integer?`, not an `Integer` or an `Object`. You can do so like this:

```
dim val1 As Integer? = If(5 > 2, Nothing, New Integer?(43))
```

By explicitly making the false branch of the operator an `Integer?`, the `Nothing` in the true branch will represent the null value, instead of the default `Integer` value.

Comment: Alternatively drop `Nothing` completely: `dim val1 As Integer? = If(5 > 2, New Integer?, 43)`