# What is VB.NET's equivalent of C#'s default keyword?

Tags: vb.net, default, nullable, dbnull, ternary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug?? If you assign a value to a nullable integer via a ternary operator, it can't become null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181493/bug-if-you-assign-a-value-to-a-nullable-integer-via-a-ternary-operator-it-can)

While this question may seem like a duplicate of many, it is actually being asked for a specific reason.  Take this code, for example:

```
Dim n As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, 1)
```

In that code, the ternary expression *should* be returning Nothing, but it's setting n to 0.  If this were C#, I could say `default(int?)` and it would work perfectly.  Now it looks like I am going to have to ditch the ternary and use a regular If block, but I really want to use the ternary.

If Nothing were truly VB.NET's equivalent to C#'s default, how can you explain this behavior?

Comment: `Nothing` in this instance equates to `default(int)` because your inferred type based on the expression is `int`, not `int?`. This can be seen with `If(true, Nothing, new Integer?(1))`

Comment: So then it is safe to say that VB.NET *doesn't* have an equivalent of C#'s default.  If it did, it could have used type inference to determine that Nothing, in this case, equates to a nullable integer's default value which is Nothing, not 0.

Comment: In an indirect way, that's correct. In C#, the `default` takes a type, which can be used for inferrence.  In VB, it seems that `Nothing` plays the passive role in this.

Comment: Wow, it IS a dupe!  I vote to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) equivalent to C#'s `default` is the keyword `Nothing`.  The code you wrote should compile just fine so long as `Id.Value` returns an `Integer` value.

The reason your updated sample is going wrong is because of the nature of `Nothing`.  In VB.NET `Nothing` is the empty value and it's convertible to any type. Now for an `If` expression, the compiler has to infer what the type of the return should be, and it does this by looking at the two value arguments.

The value `Nothing` has no type, but the literal `1` has the type `Integer`. `Nothing` is convertible to `Integer` so the compiler determines `Integer` is the best type here. This means when `Nothing` is chosen as the value, it will be interpreted as `Integer` and not `Integer?`.

The easiest way to fix this is to explicitly tell the compiler that you want `1` to be treated as an `Integer?`.

```
Dim n As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, CType(1, Integer?))
```

Comment: In my question, am I using Nothing in the ternary expression correctly?  If not, how would you modify it to do what I am trying?  Have you, by any chance, attempted to reproduce the issue using your own code?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin the code you're using is just fine. I wrote up a sample locally and it worked as expected

Comment: Okay then try the updated code I edited into my question.  When you run that single line of code, `n` is being set to Nothing as expected?  When I run it, it's being set to 0.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin that's expected.  For numeric types `Nothing` and `0` are interchangeable.  It's best to read `Nothing` as the empty value of the type I'm using it with.  For an `Integer` the empty value is `0`.

Comment: But for a nullable, it's Nothing.  Notice that I am using a nullable and not a standard value type.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin ok, I see where the current sample is going wrong.  Give me a second and I'll update my answer

Comment: Ugh.  In C#, I can go like `int? n = true ? default(int?) : 1;` without any hassle.  Oh well, thanks for your help.  Marked and upvoted.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin it's a tradeoff scenario.  In C# the `default(...)` expression includes a type hence it's explicit what type of value you want. In VB.Net though it's a typeless default value.  Shorter to type out in most cases, more generally useful than say `null` but does have this corner case.